# Rounding in an amortization table

Tags: rounding

I'm currently writing a C program that among other things generates and prints out an amortization table with numbers rounded to two digits.   I get the correct numbers everywhere, that is: monthly_payment = principal_paid + interest_paid except in the last row (last payment) where occasionally my results don't add up, and off by one.  For example:

MonthlyPay: 88.83,  PrinPaid: 87.96,  IntPaid: 0.88

Of course looking at the results printed to 6 digits it's easy to see why this is happening:

MonthlyPay: 88.834637,  PrincPaid: 87.955087,  IntPaid: 0.879551

What's the best way to handle a situation like this?
What do financial institutions do?

Comment: The last row in an amortization is typically different. It has to be computed in a slightly different way than the other rows. The final payment should be the last balance plus the interest from the last period, since this is the amount that results in zero final balance. You could do the calculations in pennies to fight round-off error. For maximal realism, make sure that all rounding of fractional pennies is in the bank's favor

Comment: I'm doing the computation slightly differently for the last payment, and that's why I'm having these rounding issues.  In any case, I ended up putting in a simple routine that checks if the sum of the rounded interest and principal payment equals monthly payment, and if  it's not, it adds one penny to either monthly payment or interest payment.  It looks like a hack, but it works like a charm.   And it always favors the bank.

Comment: @JSz - Sounds like the right solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard.

There are those who say, ["Once you round, use the rounded value for all further totals."](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1505-invoices-how-to-properly-round-and-calculate-totals)

There are others who disagree, saying that [you should sum the unrounded values to avoid accumulated rounding error](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/49141/39266). For example, 0.0666 + 0.0666 + 0.0666 + ... 15 times should approximately equal 1.0000, but if rounding each term to 2 decimal places before summing, ends up being 0.07 * 15 = 1.05! So that's the argument for using unrounded values. Your off-by-one is only off-by-*one* because you have just two terms you're summing.

I think ultimately you have to consider the pros and cons of each method. Who would be interested in the rounding errors? Just the programmers? Accounting? Customers? How does it affect those people? And can you issue a statement that clears the ambiguity, like ["Values *displayed* to 2 decimal places."](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/49178/39266) in which case you don't round anything at all, but simply display the first two decimal places everywhere.

Comment: I tried to use rounded values in the computation, but that simply doesn't work here. 
For one, in some cases there were a huge cumulative errors compared to calculations not using rounded values. 
For two, in one case the interest payment rounded to the nearest cent ended up being equal to the monthly payment! That sure lead to an interesting looking amortization table screaming at me.

Comment: Definitely don't use rounded values in the calculation. Only round if you're displaying to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Don't round in your calculations. Round only when displaying to end users.

The displayed values might be off by a cent here or there (maybe, but I doubt it). But if you round in your calculations, you'll end up with either total underreporting interest paid and overreporting principal paid, or vice versa.

If you don't round, your calculations will be correct enough that they won't make 1 cent of a difference unless you do massive loan values.